# How to use jquery text lenght

Tags: jquery, if-statement

i write this code on jquery but does not work

```
var n = $("h4");

if (n.text.length == 0) {
   n.css("background-color", "none"); 
} else { 
  n.css("background-color", "black"); 
}
```

BUT

i changed the css style and worked

```
var n = $("h4");

if (n.css("color", "white")) {
   n.css("background-color", "none"); 
} else { 
  n.css("background-color", "black"); 
}
```

I need

```
h4.text.length
```

Any ideas?

Comment: if you are looking for the text writed inside h4 tag. you need to use `innerHTML` **instead of** `text`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.text()` is a function. You need to use:

```
n.text().length
```

Moreover, this is a setter, which **always** return `true`:

```
if (n.css("color", "white")) { // This is totally wrong.
```

Comment: i know this always return true. that was for test

Comment: @YuZA then why not use  `if(true)` / `if(1)`

Comment: @YuZA Yeah, answer the above comment. Did the `n.text().length` worked?

Comment: @YuZA You are assigning: `=` is assignment. `==` is comparison. You need `if (n.text().length == 0) {`. Check: https://jsfiddle.net/nnuyymjq/.

Comment: @YuZA You didn't load anything, check this working: **https://jsfiddle.net/s1o2agft/**

Comment: @Praveen Kumar i want when h4 text is null then background color have color else background color not have any color.

i wish i write my problem correctly

Comment: @YuZA Just replace it with `transparent`. Why can't you make it yourself! Duh!!! **https://jsfiddle.net/fdua9e4f/**.